# Using GNU Emacs for Windows search functions with SUA/Interix

Tags: windows-7, windows, emacsw32, sua

I'm using GNU Emacs 23 for Windows (running on Windows 7 64-bit) and I'd like to be able to use search functions like `M-x find-dired` and `M-x find-grep-dired`.

The only Unix-like environment I am allowed access to is Services for Unix Applications (SUA, also known as Interix).

Has anyone managed to get this to work?

FWIW, I've tried creating a batch script called `bash.bat` with the following contents:

```
c:\Windows\posix.exe /u /c //usr//local//bin//bash -l %*
```

This produces the following output, when executed in emacs using `M-x find-dired`

```
c:/Users/matthewd/:
find . \( _emacs \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;
...    
c:\Users\matthewd>c:\Windows\posix.exe /u /c //usr//local//bin//bash -l -c "find . \( _emacs \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;" ...
Welcome to the SUA utilities.

DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
find: _emacs: unknown option

find exited abnormally with code 1 at Fri May 13 16:25:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you open a shell (ksh, tcsh or bash) and run `find` and/or `grep` directly?
It would be a lot easier because then the login environment gets set and you won't then be getting those errors.

You'll find a link in the Start menu under "Subsystem for Unix-based Application" to the
shells.

If you want to use bash you can get it from the [SUA Community](http://www.suacommunity.com) site (along with
hundreds of other additional programs for free).

Comment: I already run find/grep from the shell, but I'm trying to get it working under Emacs. The login environment doesn't really have anything to do with my issue, neither does the availability of bash (which I already have installed).